# set new id for element in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have code blow to change new id for a element with jquery.

```
$('.trclick').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var idright = split_right(id,'__');
  var val = $('#ims_master_test_day1__'+idright).val();

  $('#ims_master_test_day').attr( 'id', 'ims_master_test_day__' + idright );
});
```

It work but it active only one. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: What you mean with `activate`?

Comment: You cannot have two element with same id!! Seen that you already have the element with your formed id in the HTML.

Comment: What are you trying the change, the ID for the current element clicked? Or all instances of that div on the page?

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what exactly is the issue..A jsfiddle will help.

Comment: please be clear what do you want to acheive

Comment: I think the person is new here and confused how to ask the question. May be weak in english to explain the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean "it only functions the first time it's called" when you say "It work but it active only one."  The reason for that is this line of code:

```
$('#ims_master_test_day').attr( 'id', 'ims_master_test_day__' + idright );
```

You're getting the element by its id, but then changing it.  It doesn't work the second time because the element no longer has that id.  You can fix it by doing something like this:

```
var test_day = $('#ims_master_test_day')

$('.trclick').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var idright = split_right(id,'__');
  var val = $('#ims_master_test_day1__'+idright).val();

  test_day.attr( 'id', 'ims_master_test_day__' + idright );
});
```

Comment: Ah yes, caching the element for the future would work much better than caching the id :) Good one!

Comment: @aaa: If this answered your question, you should click the check mark to let everyone else know and to reward the poster.

Answer (score 0):

After you change the id the first time, you can no longer find the element to change the id the subsequent times

```
// this won't work the second time because the id is different now
$('#ims_master_test_day').attr( 'id', 'ims_master_test_day__' + idright );
```

So you need to modify your code in order to change the id every time. For example, something like this might work:

```
// cache the current id in some variable somewhere :)
var currentId;
$('.trclick').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var idright = split_right(id,'__');
  var val = $('#ims_master_test_day1__'+idright).val();

  $('#'+currentId).attr( 'id',  'ims_master_test_day__' + idright);

  // set the current id
  currentId = 'ims_master_test_day__' + idright;
});
```